# Convert Char to String in C

Tags: c, string, char

How do I convert a character to a string in C. I'm currently using `c = fgetc(fp)` which returns a character. But I need a string to be used in strcpy

Comment: Store all character in an array and then store `\0` as a last element of array. That's it.

Comment: Could you be more specific?  Based on you description, you could try something like `fscanf(pf, "%s", &buf)`.

Comment: int c;    c=fgetc(fp)//get character by character from file    and I need to be able to do strcpy(buffer,c);

Comment: why do you need to use it with `strcpy()`, exactly?

Comment: I'm amazed at how much traffic and debate this simple question has generated. The solution is two lines of code. TWO. I'm upvoting the question simply because he made a bunch of pros fall all over themselves.

Answer (score 20):

To answer the question without reading too much else into it I would

```
char str[2] = "\0"; /* gives {\0, \0} */
str[0] = fgetc(fp);
```

You could use the second line in a loop with whatever other string operations you want to keep using chars as strings.

Answer (score 8):

You could do many of the given answers, but if you just want to do it to be able to use it with `strcpy`, then you could do the following:

```
...
    strcpy( ... , (char[2]) { (char) c, '\0' } );
...
```

The `(char[2]) { (char) c, '\0' }` part will temporarily generate null-terminated string out of a character `c`.

This way you could avoid creating new variables for something that you already have in your hands, provided that you'll only need that *single-character string* just once.

Comment: That's the most syntactically obscure way of copying a string I can imagine. Not what I would suggest to a newb.

Comment: @CareyGregory I agree with that, but I think my explanation is short and understandable; making it enough not-as-much-obscure for anyone.

Comment: Excellent suggestion, but now, (MSVC: compiling as C++) it gives: "C4576: a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax." Explained a bit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270731/error-c4576-in-vs2015-enterprise).

Answer (score 7):

Using `fgetc(fp)` only to be able to call `strcpy(buffer,c);` doesn't seem right.

You could simply build this buffer on your own:

```
char buffer[MAX_SIZE_OF_MY_BUFFER];

int i = 0;
char ch;
while (i < MAX_SIZE_OF_MY_BUFFER - 1 && (ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
    buffer[i++] = ch;
}
buffer[i] = '\0';  // terminating character
```

Note that this relies on the fact that you will read less than `MAX_SIZE_OF_MY_BUFFER` characters

Answer (score 5):

I use this to convert char to string (an example) :

```
char c = 'A';
char str1[2] = {c , '\0'};
char str2[5] = "";
strcpy(str2,str1);
```

Answer (score 2):

A code like that should work:

```
int i = 0;
char string[256], c;
while(i < 256 - 1 && (c = fgetc(fp) != EOF)) //Keep space for the final \0
{
    string[i++] = c;
}
string[i] = '\0';
```

Comment: It's better to type `'\0'` rather than `0` since `'\0'` explicitly expresses that "I am assigning the terminating character here".

Comment: I think the C standard rather mention 0 instead of '\0', which simply is interpreted as 0, but I guess it depends of your coding style. I did a lot of string manipulation lately, and I got used to 0, as its faster to write ^^

Answer (score 2):

```
//example
char character;//to be scanned
char merge[2];// this is just temporary array to merge with      
merge[0] = character;
merge[1] = '\0';
//now you have changed it into a string
```

Comment: This answer is correct but [code-only answers should be avoided](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303605/4284627). Please edit to add an explanation (you can look at the other answers to see how such an explanation can look).

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working exemple :

```
printf("-%s-", (char[2]){'A', 0});
```

This will display `-A-`

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I'd say none of the answers really fits the OP's question. All he wanted/needed to do is this:

```
char c = std::fgetc(fp);
std::strcpy(buffer, &c);
```

The relevant aspect here is the fact, that the second argument of **`strcpy()`** doesn't need to be a char array / c-string. In fact, none of the arguments is a char or char array at all. They are both char pointers:

```
strcpy(char* dest, const char* src);
```

**`dest :`** A non-const char pointer

Its value has to be the memory address of an element of a writable char array (with at least one more element after that).

**`src  :`** A const char pointer

Its value can be the address of a single char, or of an element in a char array. That array must contain the special character **`\0`** within its remaining elements (starting with **`src`**), to mark the end of the c-string that should be copied.

Answer (score 0):

FYI you dont have string datatype in C. Use array of characters to store the value and manipulate it. Change your variable c into an array of characters and use it inside a loop to get values.

```
char c[10];
int i=0;
while(i!=10)
{
    c[i]=fgetc(fp);
    i++;
}
```

The other way to do is to use pointers and allocate memory dynamically and assign values.

Comment: Make your char array sufficiently large, add '\0' character at the end, to denote the end marker.