# Inline initialization of an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct, visual-studio-2015, initialization

I have this struct:

```
struct Foo {
    int a;
    int* b;
};
```

Then I'm creating an instance for it like this:

```
int x [] = { 5, 6 };
Foo y = { 2, x };
```

But, I'd like to create the `x` array inline, maybe something like this:

```
struct Foo y = { 2, (int[]) { 5, 6 } };
```

But the example above do not work... How can I achieve this?

--------- EDIT:

I'm getting this error from intellisense:

> cast to incomplete array type "int []" is not allowed

Build error:

> Error C4576   a parenthesized type followed by an initializer list is a non-standard explicit type conversion syntax

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 (v140).

Comment: If you're "creating an instance" like `Foo y = { 2, x };` then there's something missing that you don't show us. There's no type `Foo`. Please create a proper [mcve] to show us. And don't forget to tell us the full and complete error message you get.

Comment: ___Please do not change the question body once an answer is posted. You can always append to it, but changing it completely makes the answer(s) invalid.___

Comment: You can't `free` the `b` member, because the pointer value was not obtained from `malloc` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your case, `Foo` is not a type.

Try

```
struct Foo y = { 2, (int[]) { 5, 6 } };
```

<kbd><kbd>[It works as expected](https://repl.it/repls/VerticalFlawlessPreprocessor)</kbd></kbd>

---

Edit:

You only need to `free()` the memory programatically which you allocate using the allocator function (`malloc()` and family). The memory which is not returned by an allocator function, need not be `free()`-d by the programmer.

---

Edit 1:

Regarding the C4567, [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33270731/2173917)

Comment: Once you posted your answer, It seems that it works on GCC, but not on Visual Studio. I didn't imagine that this could be a platform problem...

Comment: @JoãoPaulo I was not knowing about visual studio earlier, I evaluated in GCC.

Comment: This solution *does* work with MSVC as shown by `printf("%d %d\n", y.b[0], y.b[1]);`

Comment: Thanks @WeatherVane sir, I could not see anything in the spec mentioning against it, so I assumed it'd work, but thanks for confirmation.

Comment: @WeatherVane - MS don't support any C standard past ANSI. How can it work? (Not to fault Sourav, of course, it's MS being annoying).

Comment: @StoryTeller I did not imagine it. I know it worked because I wrote, compiled and ran a small test program without any warnings, errors or faults.

Comment: @WeatherVane - What version of MSVC were you using? What you are saying is news to me

Comment: @StoryTeller Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23506.0. I don't use Visual Studio itself: I do everything with a text editor and a console.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo C is not C++. C++ is not C.

Comment: @Lundin .. and, `C/C++` is undefined behavior. :)

Comment: @Lundin re your deleted answer, I used the compiler from Visual Studio 2015. In OP's original post the keyword `struct` was missing - perhaps that was the problem. Otherwise OP's code was the same as this answer.

Comment: @JoãoPaulo An initializer list is the whole `= { ... }` thing, which is present in C and C++ both. `(int[]) { 5, 6 }` is a compound literal which is a feature only available in C, not in C++.

Comment: @WeatherVane Apparently the OP compiled C code as C++ and then compound literals aren't available.